# How to remove a system file using adb shell?

Tags: adb, linux

I have an android system file in  **/mnt/extsd/**.And I wanted to delete that file.

```
root@android:/mnt/extsd # ls -l
d---rwxr-x system   media_rw          1980-01-01 00:00 clockworkmod
root@android:/mnt/extsd #  rm -r  clockworkmod/   
Aborted
```

So, I remounted the system in write mode and tried the same with no luck.

```
root@Tron:/home/aswin# adb kill-server
root@Tron:/home/aswin# adb remount 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
remount succeeded
root@Tron:/home/aswin# adb shell rm -r /mnt/extsd/clockworkmod/ 
Aborted
```

I tried to set a 755 permission by issuing these commands , but they wont work.

```
root@android:/mnt/extsd #  ls -l
d---rwxr-x system   media_rw          1980-01-01 00:00 clockworkmod
root@android:/mnt/extsd # chmod 755 clockworkmod/                              
root@android:/mnt/extsd # ls -l                                                
d---rwxr-x system   media_rw          1980-01-01 00:00 clockworkmod
root@android:/ #  chown root /mnt/extsd/
Unable to chmod /mnt/extsd/: Operation not permitted
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you checked whether `/mnt/extsd` is writable (`ls -l /mnt |grep extsd`)? If it is not, you can neither `chmod` nor `rm` its direct contents.